# Using std::function to write a function that returns a function

Tags: c++, lambda

Our C++ professor told us to practise the use of std::function, lambda and pointers to functions.
He asked us to:

> Write the function
>  `std::function<bool(float)> interval(float low, float high)`. The function should accept two values `low` and `high` and should return a function.
> The function returned will check if it's parameter is inside or outside the interval (low,high) and will return `true` or `false` accordingly.

I tackled the problem with this code.

The function declaration:

```
std::function<bool(float)> interval (float low,float high){
    return [low,high](float f){ return (f > low) && (f < high); };
}
```

How is it used in the main:

```
std::function<bool(float)> interval (float low,float high);
bool res = interval(10, 20)(150);
std::cout << res;
```

And it works.
But I am not sure how the solution is elegant, or "best practise".

In particular, this call `bool res = interval(10, 20)(150);` is what scares me.
It is really awful to call it like this.
How would you have done the excersize? Do you find my solution clear?

Comment: "Is it best practice" isn't really a useful question for homework problems. The task is to use the technique. If you had something that you called like `interval(10, 20, 150)` that would be wrong.

Comment: On the other hand, it may help you to understand the value of this if you split up the call. For example, you could have `auto isLegalSpeed = interval(0, 60);` and on another line `if isLegalSpeed(currentSpeed)` which would be a lot more readable than `if interval(0, 60, currentSpeed)`

Comment: Even better, because these lambdas are objects, you can put them in data structures like maps and arrays. For example, you might have something like `speedCheck[highway] = interval(50, 70);` and `speedCheck[city] = interval(10, 30);` That allows for very powerful constructions indeed: if you had a list of speed camera readings from a list of roads, you could then test `speedCheck[roadType](speed)` for each reading instead of the much more verbose `if roadType == city {...`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it almost conforms to the spec (I think those tests should be `>=` and `<=` given that's an *inclusive* interval).  You might want to consider what happens if a NaN value is passed in - since they are neither less-than nor greater-than actual numbers, we'll return `false`, which seems reasonable.  It's probably not a good idea to create an interval with NaN as start or end of the range, though!

Though it wasn't your choice, I would question the use of `float` rather than `double` here (actually, in real code, I'd probably make it a template function so it can work with any type that has a partial ordering).

If you don't like the chained call syntax, you can separate out using a variable, and that's likely to be a more common case than building and immediately using just once as shown in the question:

```
auto is_valid = interval(10, 20);
for (auto v: values) {
     if (!is_valid(v)) {
         std::cerr << v << " out of range\n";
    }
}
```